# Visual studio code intellisense doesn't see html classes

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

VS code intellisense doesn't see html classes.
Is it even possible to make this as I want?

Extensions don't help

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, I don't believe VSC has this feature implemented into IntelliSense. However, there are popular marketplace extensions that implement what you are looking for!

This one will autocomplete css->html https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion or by searching `Zignd.html-css-class-completion` in the marketplace section inside VSC.

And this one will autocomplete html->css: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion or by searching `solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion` in the marketplace section inside VSC.

Comment: This extension works differently from what i want, it completes class names in html file, not in css file as i want.

Comment: The extension is capable of that. You just have to have the CSS file linked in the head of the HTML document as you would normally.

Comment: Yea, I didnt link css but it  still doesn't change anything.

Comment: My apologies, the extension seems to only do the reverse of what you are looking for. The extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=solnurkarim.html-to-css-autocompletion I have tested to work the way you are looking for.

Comment: That's it. Thank you